# A theorem from Joseph Bak's complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm a undergraduate student studying complex analysis and the used textbook is written by Joseph Bak and Donald J. Newman. My question is about theorem 6-11 from the book related to entire functions as follows:

> If $f$ is entire and if $f\left( z\right)\to \infty$ as $z\to \infty$ , then $f$ is a polynomial.

In this proof, the author makes use of Corollary 5-9, which states the function
\begin{equation}
g\left(z\right)=\frac{f\left(z\right)}{\left(z-a_1\right)\left(z-a_2\right)\cdots \left(z-a_N\right)}
\end{equation}
is entire and $g_\left(a_i\right)=\lim_{z\to a_i}g\left(z\right)$ for each $1\leq i \leq N$, if $f$ is entire and $f\left(a_1\right)=f\left(a_2\right)=\cdots =f\left(a_N\right)=0$. Then it is claimed that $g$ is never 0, which sounds strange to me since my understanding is that when $z$ is $a_i$, we have $g\left(a_i\right)=f'\left(a_i\right)$ but I think $f'\left(a_i\right)$ is not necessarily equal to 0.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: For those of us that don't have the book, are there any other hypotheses on $f$ or the $a_i$?  How does this work if $g=\frac{\sin z}{z}$?

Comment: @saulspatz I spent some time thinking about this, too, and what I suspect is that the condition $f(z)\to\infty$ means that the function blows up in all directions, i.e. $1/f(1/z)$ has a zero at $0$. But this is just a guess on my part

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry for the confusion. It would be clearer that $f\left(z\right) \to \infty$ occurs when $z\to \infty$.

Comment: $f(z)\to\infty$ as $z\to\infty$ means that for every $N>0$ there exists a $R$ such that $|z|>R$ implies $|f(z)|>N$.  But this doesn't answer my question.  What exactly are the hypotheses of the corollary?  As stated, it's false when $f(z)=\sin z, N=1, a_1=0$

Comment: @saulspatz $\sin z$ doesn't satisfy the conditions because it doesn't grow unboundedly in all directions and has an infinite number of zeros, but the way I think about it is that $f(1/z)$ has an essential singularity at $0$, so that can never be turned into a zero. There must be some corollary of Rouche's theorem that gives unbounded growth implies finite number of zeros.

Comment: In the definition of $g$, each zero of $f$ is supposed to occur as often as its multiplicity demands. That means $g(a_i) = f'(a_i)$ only if $a_i$ is a simple zero.

Comment: For the sake of clarity, I quote the whole statement of Corollary 5-9:
Suppose $f$ is entire with zeros at $a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_N$. Then if g is defined by
\begin{equation}
g\left(z\right)=\frac{f\left(z\right)}{\left(z-a_1\right)\left(z-a_2\right)\cdots \left(z-a_N\right)},
\end{equation}
for $z\neq a_k$, $\lim_{z \to a_k} $ $g\left( z\right)$ exists for $k=1,2,\cdots, N$, and if $g\left( a_k\right)$ by these limits, then $g$ is entire.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yeah, I thought about it for a while and found you are right. No wonder the corollary doesn't mention what the value of $g$ at $a_k$ is.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I'm afraid I cannot see why that $f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$ has an essential singularity at 0 implies $g$ is never 0. Do I misunderstand something?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3144069/if-f-is-an-entire-function-that-goes-to-infinity-f-is-a-polynomial

Comment: @JCH Honestly, I saw the post before I post my own. I cannot see the proof shown in the post is same as I read in my textbook. Maybe I should look to another proof and get rid of the one in my textbook.

Comment: @Eric that was a rebuttal to the "counterexample" $\sin z$, its definitely not true for the functions we care about.

Comment: @NinadMunshi You mean that $g$ is never 0 is not true or the whole theorem 6-11?

Comment: If you divide away the multiplicities of the roots, it cannot be zero anywhere.

Comment: @NinadMunshi That's because $f$ is entire and hence it has a Taylor expansion, right?